# What do we call assigning different types of objects to a variable in Python?

Tags: python

I need to know, what is it called, assigning different types of objects to a variable, in Python. For example,

```
 a = 2
 a = 'string'
```

Comment: You can do this in PHP, JavaScript, and many other languages. It's called dynamic typing.

Comment: You *aren't* assigning "a string value to an integer".  You are assigning a string value to a variable, that has no type of its own.  In Python, 'type' is a property of values, not variables.

Answer (score 0):

That is know as "dynamic typing" (as in the type of the variable is dynamic).

It's different from other languages like Java that use "static typing", where the variable must remain a single type.

Comment: I mean Java (and most other modern languages) *can* do that, but they can choose not to. `Object a = 2; a = "string";` works just fine.

Comment: @JoachimSauer wouldn't that be implicit casting since everything in Java extends from Object?

Comment: Also more specifically, can't we call it `duck typing`?

Comment: @Chrispresso Duck Typing is when something is considered to be an appropriate type if it has the proper methods/attributes for a given use. That goes hand in hand with dynamic typing, but isn't what's being asked here afaict.